# ASP.NET MVC RedirectToAction Default Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

How do I redirect to a Controller without defining the Action?
*(it will default to the default action as defined in the routes config)*

**Example**

`return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error" new { messageId = errorMessageId} );`

Url displayed to user is: `http:mydomain/Error/Index/1001`

**Preferred**

`return RedirectToAction(null, "Error" new { messageId = errorMessageId} );`

URL I want to displayed to user is: `http:mydomain/Error/1001`

When I type the URL manually, it works fine, so I know my routes are working.

I just cant figure out how to do it using Redirectxxxx in MVC.

Comment: You can use direct
`Redirect("url goes here")` 
in MVC where you can put directly your url "http:mydomain/Error/1001"

Comment: `When I type the URL manually, it works fine, so I know my routes are working.` - Not necessarily. Incoming URL and outgoing URL are two different methods and it is quite possible to configure routing in such a way that they don't match. Please post your route configuration - it is possible your sample URL "works" because it is matching a different route than you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`RedirectToRoute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoroute(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToRoute%28System.Object%29).

```
return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Error", messageId = errorMessageId });
```

Alternatively, there is `Redirect` coupled with `Url.RouteUrl`.

```
return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Error", messageId = errorMessageId }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected internal RedirectToAction(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues
)
```

Here is the **RedirectToAction** method you can define your own route here without using the action name.

For more info about routing check this:
[Routing](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html)